# get value from multiple button clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of button according to the click event but it's returning null value. can anyone suggest me proper way to do it ?

code::

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>elevator</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="btn0" onclick="inFunction(0)" >0</button>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="inFunction(1)" >1</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="inFunction(2)" >2</button>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="inFunction(3)" >3</button>
  <button id="btn4" onclick="inFunction(4)" >4</button>
  <button id="btn5" onclick="inFunction(5)" >5</button>

 <script>
 function inFunction(clickedValue) {
      var btnValue = document.getElementById(clickedValue.id).value;
      console.log(btnValue);
}
 </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*clickedValue* in your method is a number, not an object.  Send in 'this' or the id.  No need to getElementById if you already have the element though.

Also either get the innerText, or set the input='...' attribute if you want it different than what is displayed.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>elevator</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="btn0" onclick="inFunction(this)" >0</button>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="inFunction(this)" >1</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="inFunction(this)" >2</button>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="inFunction(this)" >3</button>
  <button id="btn4" onclick="inFunction(this)" >4</button>
  <button id="btn5" onclick="inFunction(this)" >5</button>

 <script>
 function inFunction(ele) {
      var btnValue = ele.innerText;
      console.log(btnValue);
}
 </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks steven for answering my question. I have small doubt Does this refer to a current button and innerText refers to the text which I give to the button?

Comment: 'this' is the element (button).  Most javascript callbacks work that way.

Comment: Your original code would have worked, using id of the button to get the button itself!

Comment: var btnValue = document.getElementById(clickedValue).value; I tried this but doesn't work

Comment: If you wanted to use value, you could have done <button id="btn5" value='5' onclick="inFunction(this)" >5</button

Comment: your solution seems fine to me

Comment: The value of the button is not the same as the innerText or innerHTML

Comment: Last thing @Riya, with input elements we usually use attributes name='foo', and value='xxx'.  These are what gets posted in a form.